# Run python script in PyPy

Tags: python, pypy

I have a python script developed in Spyder using Python 2.7.4.
This script is called from another python script using:

```
execfile('script.py')
```

I'd like to know how can I run both python scripts using PyPy (I'd like this because it is faster than standard Python). Thanks!

P.S.: I've already installed PyPy in Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the first Python script using `pypy scriptname.py` on the command line. The code run by `execfile()` will also be run in PyPy, because the main script (`execfile()`) is being run in PyPy.

Comment: when I run pypy from the command line (I had to run it from the source directory) I have this error: `pypy Job-M1-3_run2.py` `File "<stdin>", line 1` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and point to the space between `pypy` and the script name. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That means you're in PyPy. The command I gave was a shell command not a Python one.

Comment: So I should write `pypy scriptname.py` for instance in Spyder command line? Thanks

Comment: I've not used Spyder, but it should have a place in the settings to specify a command to use for running scripts, or you may even be able to specify multiple configurations (e.g. for Python 2 and Python 3). In the latter case you'd just add PyPy as another configuration and specify the PyPy executable, similar to how Python is specified in the others.