# How do I get my script to run on pypy instead of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

I have script that I'm hoping pypy can speed up.  I have unzipped pypy to an x86 folder and added the path.  I ran pypy in the command line and it returns the current version.  But my question is simply - how do I switch my script to run on pypy and not python?  Do I add something to the top of the script or do something in the command promp?  Thanks.

I'm frankly not sure what I was expecting.  I thought it would be straight forward but theres not many guides online on how to use pypy.

Comment: Just run `pypy myscript.py`?

Comment: Instead of  `python your_script.py`, use `pypy your_script.py` in command prompt.

Comment: when I try that in the command prompt I get: C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy\pypy3.10-v7.3.13-win64\pypy.exe: can't open file C:\Users\sam\test.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.  The location of the script is on my desktop if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

To run your .py program using 'pypy', you need to run it like this :

```
pypy program.py
```

Got the information from this post :

[Run python script in PyPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595337/run-python-script-in-pypy)

Comment: I go into the command prompt and type pypy test.py and it gives me: "C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy\pypy3.10-v7.3.13-win64\pypy.exe: can't open file C:\Users\sam\test.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory."  Im trying to run a script and the location of it is on my desktop.

Comment: Did you check the file's execution right right ? You can modify it with chmod on linux.

Comment: Its working code if thats what you're asking.  It works with Python execution.  Im on windows.

Comment: Ok so the problem doesn't come from access rights. I have no more idea for the cause of issue. 
You might check the path used to run the file, or try to run the file from the file's directory (if you're not already doing it).

Comment: I don't think the file is running using 'pypy', it would be called 'pypy' i guess... Did you try from the command prompt ?